# Seems like a metaphor

Tags: knowledge, cipher

## Let's Draw!

**STEP 1**

```
DDD
DDD
```

**STEP 2**

```
VVD
DCC
```

**STEP 3**

```
 N
VVD
DCC
 U
```

**STEP 4**

```
 N
VVK
ECC
 U
```

*...so what'd you make?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With these steps, we have made

> the [Cool S](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_S) using [flag semaphore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore):
>
>  [image: image of the letters in the puzzle, with their flag semaphore symbols overlaid on them]